# Can the LCT and MCT for Lebesgue integrable functions be viewed as a lattice completeness result?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lattice-orders, gauge-integral

The set of Lebesgue integrable functions form a lattice under pointwise min and max (also more generally for R, Henstock-Kurzweil integrable functions with an upper or lower bound form a lattice as well).

The convergence theorems look a lot like countable completeness for that lattice. Is there an alternative formulation or generalization of them that is exactly that or further in that direction?